# Customise Arc mouse gestures on windows

Tags: windows, powershell, touchpad, gestures

I recently bought arc mouse and the lack of gestures in it are a bit disappointing. The microsoft mouse and keyboard centre software lets you customise a 3 finger click. So it means the mouse can detect 3 fingers. But thats all it lets you do.

I found this solution https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/7n49t9/backforward_gesture_for_arc_mouse_in_chrome/ which tells that it can detect two finger swipe also.

Can i write a script in windows that will let me detect all of its gestures and then i customize it according to particular softwares? For example when a web browser is opened the swipe will mean go back and forward but when some other software is open then swipe will have different behaviour.

I just want to see its capabilities and tinker with it fully.